# How can i divide the value i acquire on an array with a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
student_names = []
test1_scores = []
test2_scores = []
test3_scores = []
total_scores = []

total_students = int(input("How many students are in you class? "))
counter = int(0)

while counter < total_students:
    student_name = str(input("What is the name of the student %s " % (counter+1)))

if student_name.isalpha() == True:
    student_names.append(student_name)
    test1_score = int(input("Please enter the score for test 1: "))
    if test1_score >= 0 and test1_score <= 20:
        test1_scores.append(test1_score)
        if student_name.isalpha() == True:
            student_names.append(student_name)
            test2_score = int(input("Please enter the score for test 2: "))
            if test2_score >= 0 and test2_score <= 25:
                test2_scores.append(test2_score)
                if student_name.isalpha() == True:
                    student_names.append(student_name)
                    test3_score = int(input("Please enter the score for test 3: "))
                    if test3_score >= 0 and test3_score <= 35:
                        test3_scores.append(test3_score)
                        counter += 1
                    total_scores.append(test1_score + test2_score + test3_score)
                    print ("The total score is %s " %(total_scores))
                    if total_students == counter:
                        average = total_scores / (3 * total_students)
                        print ("The average score is %s " %(average))
```

If you look at the bottom part of my code, you can see i want to divide the array called `total_scores` by the test scores x  the number of students, so i can achieve an average marks for the students. But i get the following error:

```
average = total_scores / (3 * total_students)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the total_scores array:

```
for score in total_scores:
    total += score
average = total/3*total_students
```

Comment: This won't work as `total` is undefined, but given that we only need to refer to `total` once this whole thing can be simplified with the one liner `average = sum(total_scores)/(3*total_students)`. Do note the parenthesis!